# how to track down an internal port redirection?

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to understand something with X11 and one fact that I discovered is that the X display stuff seems to be sent through a port called "localhost:11"

So I tried the netstat -n | grep ':11'

but no results were matched.

What am I missing?

Isn't this supposed to be something called internal port redirecting(or something similar...)?

Hope someone could enlighten me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localhost:11 is not a port is a display number (like a session number) regarding X11. So you can't see it with netstat command.

The X connections are like this:

```
hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
```

Somme additional information here : http://www.hungry.com/~jamie/xexport.html

Comment: `localhost:11` is a display over TCP. So it can be seen with netstat but the port is 6011, not 11.

Answer (score 0):

As Boogy's answer says, that address scheme is more likely to be a display address. Port 11 is traditionally attributed to systat, an early mechanism to monitor the system running processes.

Recall that if you do a netstat, you would get the port name directly. To get port numbers, you need to add the `-n` option to [netstat](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=netstat&section=1):

> *-n*    Show network addresses and ports as numbers.  Normally netstat attempts to resolve addresses and ports, and display them symbolically.